# Calling a remote EJB hosted on WebSphere Full Profile(v7) from app. running in Liberty

Tags: websphere-liberty

I have:

- Application A running in Liberty Profile (8.5.5.7)
- Application B running in WAS Full Profile V7, hosting EJB called MyBean.

I want to invoke MyBean's methods from application A.

I'm programmatically doing the lookup for MyBean with code as below, based on the documentation at:http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_ejb_remote.html

```
String corbaURL = "corbaname::wasv7Server:wasv7Port#ejb/global/B/MyBean/beans.\\MyBean!com\\.acme\\.MyBeanRemoteInterface";
Object ref = new InitialContext().lookup(corbaURL);
// .. boilerplate code for narrowing the remote object and calling the remote method.
```

The Liberty where the app. A is running has the ejbRemote-3.2 feature enabled.
The application B deployed in WAS7 full profile had application name B and EJB module MyBean and MyBean's deployment descriptor is:

```
<session id="Session_beans.MyBean">
    <ejb-name>beans.MyBean</ejb-name>
    <home>com.acme.MyBeanHome</home>
    <remote>com.acme.MyBeanRemote</remote>
    <ejb-class>com.acme.MyBean</ejb-class>
    ...
</session>
```

When executing the lookup in app. A (in Liberty) I got a NameNotFoundException,
and I'm wondering if the LocationService at the WAS Full Profile V7 is understanding the corba name URL being sent by Liberty since V7, afaik, doesn't support JEE6; if this is the case how can I invoke the the bean MyBean from A running in the Liberty Profile? Can I use ejbRemote-3.2 feature and just use a different corba name URL, if so what is the correct URL to use?

## UPDATE

As per @bkail recommendation changed the lookup URL to:

```
String corbaURL = "corbaname::wasv7Server:wasv7Port#beans\\.MyBean" ;
// dumpNameSpace shows: 
// (top)/nodes/napp_srmwrk1_app-FULL/servers/AppServer/beans.MyBean
// 8    Bound Java type: com.acme.MyBeanHome
// 8    Local Java type: org.omg.stub.java.rmi._Remote_Stub
```

After the change still getting the NameNotFoundException. The stack trace is:

```
16:21:35.580 [Default Executor-thread-51] ERROR qsr - NamingException
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: null
at     
com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.ExceptionMapper.mapException(ExceptionMapper.java:61) ~ [na:1.8.0_60]
at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.callResolve(CNCtx.java:500) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.lookup(CNCtx.java:539) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:205) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161) ~[na:na]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at net.gbm.App.doGet(App.java:65) ~[mnr.war:na]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [com.ibm.ws.javaee.servlet.3.1_1.0.10.jar:na]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [com.ibm.ws.javaee.servlet.3.1_1.0.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1287) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1158) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4867) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31.osgi.webapp.WebApp31.handleRequest(WebApp31.java:523) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer31_1.0.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:997) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.1.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:341) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:470) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:404) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:284) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:255) [com.ibm.ws.transport.http_1.0.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.10.jar:na]
at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018) [com.ibm.ws.channelfw_1.0.10.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound:   IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFoundHelper.read(NotFoundHelper.java:72) ~[com.ibm.ws.org.apache.yoko.corba.spec.1.5_1.0.10.jar:1.8.0_60]
at org.omg.CosNaming._NamingContextStub.resolve(_NamingContextStub.java:251) ~[com.ibm.ws.org.apache.yoko.corba.spec.1.5_1.0.10.jar:1.8.0_60]
at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.callResolve(CNCtx.java:486) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
... 31 common frames omitted
```

Thanks,

Comment: what features do you have enabled on your Application A Liberty server?

Comment: I have : ejbRemote-3.2 and servlet-3.1

Comment: I wonder why IBM does not put a simple working example in github for these scenarios "a liberty-app calling was-full-ejb".  Am I not googling with right keywords?

Answer (score 1):

The `corbaname:` URLs listed in the "Using enterprise JavaBeans with remote interfaces on the Liberty profile" topic are the names used to access EJBs running in the Liberty profile.  To connect to an EJB on a full profile server, you need to use the binding name from the full profile, which likely starts with `ejb/...` rather than `ejb/global/...`.  See the "Default binding pattern" section of the [EJB 3.0 application bindings overview](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html) topic in the Knowledge Center.

Unlike the Liberty profile, the full profile mirrors the JNDI default namespace to the CosNaming context, so you should copy the relevant JNDI name from the `CNTR0167I` message in SystemOut.log (the JNDI name that does **not** start with `java:global`).  Alternatively, run the `PROFILE_HOME/bin/dumpNameSpace` command on the full profile to dump the namespace, and you should be able to find the binding name.

Comment: Bkail, If code is run in a full profile instead of liberty, using the old style way of looking the bean, it can success fully find the bean by name.  java.util.Properties p = new java.util.Properties();
 p.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://wasv7Server:wasv7Port");            
 p.put(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
 p.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass", "com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB");
 
     Context ctx = new InitialContext(p);
     Object ref = ctx.lookup("beans.MyBean");

Comment: A dump namespace in the V7 (hosting the bean) server shows:  8 (top)/nodes/napp_srmwrk1_app-FULL/servers/AppServer/beans.MyBean
 8    Bound Java type: com.acme.MyBeanHome
 8    Local Java type: org.omg.stub.java.rmi._Remote_Stub

Comment: @rsp Then the equivalent would be `corbaname::wasv7Server:wasv7Port#beans.MyBean` as your lookup string.

Comment: unfortunately I got the same NotFoundException, these are the top frames in the stack trace:javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: null
at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.ExceptionMapper.mapException(ExceptionMapper.java:61) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.callResolve(CNCtx.java:502) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtx.lookup(CNCtx.java:541) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:203)
at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:161) 
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)

Comment: Sorry, try `"corbaname::wasv7Server:wasv7Port#beans\\.MyBean"`.  If that doesn't work, you should update your question with the full stack trace.

Comment: question updated with full stack trace after changing URL to escape the '.'

Answer (score 0):

Let me share my experience of very similar work that I did just yesterday.
Hope this helps somebody who searches the stackoverflow.

First I downloaded Wlp8.5.5.8 and tried adding features like ejbRemote3.2. It was not available for reasons I am unaware of.
Then I googled to find the wlp having ejbRemote3.2 feature
Downloaded that
Added following features to the ServerConfiguration.
How to add these features to Serverconfiguration? Please refer the following link: 
[Liberty Profile - Remote EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327301/liberty-profile-remote-ejb)
Praveen has made a spoon-feed, thanks to him

```
    <feature>javaee-7.0</feature>
    <feature>ejbRemote-3.2</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
```

Added the following 6 lines of code in my servlet deployed in Liberty profile

```
    Properties ejbProps = new Properties();
    ejbProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ejbUrl);
    InitialContext ffmContext = new InitialContext(ejbProps);
    Object remoteObject = ffmContext.lookup(ejbName);
    MyBeanRemote myBean = PortableRemoteObject.narrow(remoteObject, MyBean.class);
    myBean.callingMethod();
```

And the magic worked: MyBean method got invoked/called.
Note: I had MyBean stub jar file generated and placed in my servlet deployed in wlp

Comment: what is the ejbUrl ?